# How Can I make measure SUM my amount according to level and parent category? using power bi

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery, powerpivot

I have two tables in power bi, the Invoices table and the Categories table. In the Invoices table, I have a column for CategID and a column for sales amount. In the Categories table, I have columns for ID , Name, level, and parentID. In the Categories table, there are main categories with level 2, such as:

| Name | Level | ID | ParentID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| food | 2 | 0012 | 0 |
| Games | 2 | 0013 | 0 |

etc...

And the subcategories under them have level 3 and are linked to the level 2 categories through the parent ID. For example:

| Name | Level | ID | ParentID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| tomato | 3 | 001201 | 0012 |
| cake | 3 | 001202 | 0012 |
| fish | 3 | 001203 | 0012 |
| kids games | 3 | 001301 | 0013 |
| electronic games | 3 | 001302 | 0013 |

the Main category and subcategory in same table.

The two tables are linked by the (ID) column in the Categories table and the CategID  column in the Invoices table. I would like to calculate the sales amount for each of the categories 'food' and 'Games' and etc.. from the Invoices table.

keep in mind "the name of category and subcategory are changing depending on customer"

Answer (score 0):

Create a Measure with:

```
Category L2 Sales amount = 
  CALCULATE(
    SUM( 'Invoices'[Sales amount] ),
    ALL(Categories),
    Categories[ParentID] IN DISTINCT(Categories[ID])
  )
```

Comment: but this measure gives me the sales amount of all categories, I want sales amount of each main category.

Comment: Have you tried it? https://i.stack.imgur.com/PcE9a.png

Comment: Following-up - any further help needed on this one?